# Need of Typescript definition files in Angular2

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, typescript-typings

I am using Typescript for some time and I know that I need to include references of the d.ts files, in order to get intellisense in the Visual Studio 2015 (and other IDEs). I have another project using Angular2 with Typescript and somehow the Visual Studio 2015 provides  intellisense without having any reference of d.ts files. Does Angular2 provide definitions for the most well known libraries or something else is happening that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install typings globally

**npm install -g typings**

To install library.d.ts file use

**typings install dt~YOUR_LIBRARY_NAME --save --global**

Refer https://github.com/typings/typings for further details

Refer http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/ to know whether d.ts file available for the library you look for.

Comment: As of typings version 1.0 this is the correct syntax though you will want to use the typings registry when and wherever possible. Also, you can simply 'typings search <packageName>'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does, you need first to install [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) in your project (or globally with `-g` flag) by doing:

```
npm i typings --save
```

Then you can add types for you libraries like so:

```
typings install LIBRARY_NAME --save
```